# window.onbeforeunload in Chrome: what is the most recent fix?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

Obviously, window.onbeforeunload has encountered its fair share of problems with Chrome as I've seen from all the problems I've encountered. What's the most recent work around?

The only thing I've got even close to working is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802007/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "alert" };
```

However, if I substitute return "alert" with something like alert("blah"), I get nothing from Chrome.

I saw in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790854/window-onbeforeunload-not-working-in-chrome) that Google purposefully blocks this. Good for them... but what if I want to make an AJAX call when someone closes the window? In my case, I want to know when someone has left the chatroom on my website, signalled by the window closing.

I want to know if there's a way to either 
(a): fix the window.onbeforeunload call so that I can put AJAX in there
or
(b): get some other way of determining that a window has closed in Chrome

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    var x =logout();
    return x;
});
function logout(){
        jQuery.ajax({
        });
        return 1+3;
}
```

A little mix and match, but it worked for me. The 1+3 makes sure that the logout function is being called (you'll see 4 if it's successful on the popup when you try to leave).

Comment: This does not work in chrome and it will also pop up an alert. Is there a way to ignore the alert in chrome?

Comment: @varatis "4 --- Are you sure you want to leave this page?" is the confirm dialog I get. But the workaround I've found is to `return null`.

Comment: Hii,This code is not working for me. Do i need to add some jQuery js file or something else ?

Comment: Well, you do need to have jQuery. What's the problem you're getting?

Comment: Why not just return 4 instead of 1+3?

Comment: @Lior It's just an example.. it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: This does not work, it doesn't output the custom message.

Comment: Does setTimeout() work in the logout method. It's not working for anything more than 1 Sec.

Comment: For anyone that turns up here, custom message are deprecated by most browsers, reason being that they were abused by some sites, confusing users. So now the message is a generic string which is not controllable by the web page itself. regardless of what string you return. Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) for more detailed information and specific browser behaviours

Answer (score 11):

As of Chrome 117, Chromium has met the standard. The following is tested with Chrome 122.0.6261.129 and Edge 122.0.2365.92.

[Test with StackBlitz!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-txmlss?file=script.js)

- The [standard states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#beforeunloadevent) that prompting can be controlled by canceling the event or setting the return value to a [non-null value](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#events).
- The standard states that authors should use Event.preventDefault() instead of returnValue.
- The [standard states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-documents) that the message shown to the user is not customizable.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // Cancel the event as recommended by the standard.
    e.preventDefault();
    // Alternatively, cancel the event by setting `returnValue`.
    e.returnValue = '';
});
    
window.location = 'about:blank';
```

Prior to 117, Chrome required `returnValue` to be a non-null value whether set as the return value from the handler or by reference on the event object.

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
    e.returnValue = '';
});
    
window.location = 'about:blank';
```

Comment: @Giulio Caccin the feature was released briefly in 113 but was rolled backed due to breaking a health critical user (issue#1442624). It should be available in 117.

Comment: In recent experience with Chrome: calling `event.preventDefault()` did not cause the before unload prompt to appear, setting `event.returnValue = ''` did.

Comment: @Pathogen Yes, that is what the answer describes for versions prior to 117.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more straightforward approach.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return "You should keep this page open.";
});
```

The returned message can be anything you want, including the empty string if you have nothing to add to the message that Chrome already shows. The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried the same thing and it does not work. The alert shows up correctly but without my custom message.

Comment: @c4k i think something in the latest chrome update broke this.  In my case, the returned custom message was working a week ago but after a chrome patch got installed it no longer does.

Comment: @Chronozoa, you are correct:  https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload),

> The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property
>   of the Event object and return the same string.

This is the following

```
window.addEventListener( 'beforeunload', function(ev) { 
    return ev.returnValue = 'My reason';
})
```

Comment: This is kind of the right idea, but you forgot to add the 'beforeunload' event to the listener.

Comment: Thanks very much!  This worked on Chrome 63; returning the string without assigning `returnValue` was not enough.

Comment: doesn't seem to entirely work for me on  Chrome version " 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)" or Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit) - asks for confirm but not with custom message. I tried the example from the page cited directly and got the same results.

Comment: @BeepBop custom messages are prevented for security reason

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem why it wasn't working in my app:

Note that the user must interact with the page somehow (clicking somewhere) before closing its window, otherwise beforeunload is ignored in order not prevent abuse.

Comment: hi, you probably forgot to paste your answer?