# Call a javascript method on page refresh in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onbeforeunload, page-refresh

I need to call javascript method when someone presses f5 or refreshes a page. For this I am using following javascript. It works in all browsers except chrome.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  myJsMethodToCall();
};
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onbeforeunload in Chrome: what is the most recent fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626059/window-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-what-is-the-most-recent-fix)

Comment: I did try the link above. But its not working in any of the browsers.