# DirtyForms does not work properly with $.blockUI

Tags: jquery-blockui, jquery-dirtyforms

I'm using [DirtyForms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) and [$.blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) plugin, the latter to change pages  when clicking on links (in my app, some pages take a couple of seconds more to load and a visual feedback is fine).

When I change field content and then click any link, DirtyForms is triggered: but when I cancel the process to stay on the page, `$.blockUI` starts its game, resulting in a stuck page

```js
$('form[method="post"]').dirtyForms();
$('a').on('click', function(){
 $.blockUI();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>

<p>Change the field content to activate DirtyForms, then click on the link.<br>
When the popup appears, click on "cancel" to stay on the page.<br>
Watch blockUI getting fired as the link is going to be followed</p>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
<a href="https://google.com">click me after changing field content</a>
```

Please, any solution?

EDIT: I also tried with `stay.dirtyforms` and `afterstay.dirtyforms` events, but they have no effect. `defer.dirtyforms` seems to work but the event is triggered twice (I put a `console.log()` to check) and I am not sure this is the way to go...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I've edit my answer*: I've added some line of code to disable first the `onbeforeunload` dialog alert, [taken from here](https://gist.github.com/woss/3c2296d9e67e9b91292d). And at the end a link to an answer with another idea you can try.

**My idea:** you have to prevent the default link action and use the $.blockUI [Modal Dialogs methods](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog) to open a custom dialog, then catch the link attribute `href` from the link put it inside a variable and use the variable value for the `#yes` button of the dialog.

See if this solution can meet your needs

```js
/* beforeunload bind and unbind taken from https://gist.github.com/woss/3c2296d9e67e9b91292d */

// call this to restore 'onbeforeunload'
var windowReloadBind = function(message) {
  window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    if (message.length === 0) {
       message = '';
    };
  
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
       event = window.event;
    };
    if (event) {
       event.returnValue = message;
    };
    return message;
  }
};

// call this to prevent 'onbeforeunload' dialog
var windowReloadUnBind = function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return null;
   };
};

var linkToFollow; // href to follow

$('form[method="post"]').dirtyForms();

$('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        windowReloadUnBind(); // prevent dialog
 $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' } });
        linkToFollow = $(this).attr('href');
});

$('#no').click(function() { 
        $.unblockUI();
        return false; 
});

$('#yes').click(function() { 
        $(window.location).attr('href', linkToFollow); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>

<p>Change the field content to activate DirtyForms, then click on the link.<br>
When the popup appears, click on "cancel" to stay on the page.<br>
Watch blockUI getting fired as the link is going to be followed</p>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
<a href="https://google.com" class="link">click me after changing field content</a>
<div id="question" style="display:none; cursor: default"> 
    <h6>Would you like to contine?.</h6> 
    <input type="button" id="yes" value="Yes" /> 
    <input type="button" id="no" value="No" /> 
</div>
```

**Other idea taken from another answer:** Other idea would be to make a simple `jQuery.ajax({})` call before return value in `beforeunload` [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626059/window-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-what-is-the-most-recent-fix/9628365#9628365)

Comment: Thanks Emanuele: seems a little bit tricky to make it work but I appreciate the time spent on my question

Comment: Yes it's a work around solution. Thank you for your feedback